# What happens under the hood when I create a socket in Python?

Tags: python, c, sockets

I have a UDPClient.py which creates a socket:

```
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(), (serverName, serverPort))
```

What I'm interested in is what happens under the hood with that `sendto` function.

If I CTRL-click on the function in VSCode, I get this

```
    @overload
    def sendto(self, __data: ReadableBuffer, __address: _Address) -> int: ...
```

from the _socket.pyi file in Python's standard library. However, this function is not implemented and I can't seem to find an implementation. I did, however, find [this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sendto.html#:%7E:text=The%20sendto()%20function%20shall,mode%2C%20dest_addr%20shall%20be%20ignored.&text=Specifies%20the%20socket%20file%20descriptor.) which makes me think that this function is implemented in C somewhere. So my questions then are:

(1) Where could I find this implementation in C, if it is indeed in C?

(2) How exactly does Python 'see' this implementation? I assume this is a deeper question of what happens when you run a python script.

I'd appreciate a detailed answer on this but I'm also happy to be given reading from somewhere where I can see all of these details explained. Thank you!

Comment: See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Modules/socketmodule.c

Comment: It's gonna call the suitable socket lib which in turn depends on OS. It's still very high level code at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can say that `sendto` calls the function of the underlying OS

here's `sock_sendto`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4238

also check out `sock_sendto_impl` above `sock_sendto`